# Why does the form not receive select data in AntD?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, antd

I am using AntD select.
When I put select into a separate component, the form does not see the value
Tell me why the form does not receive data on submit ?

[Example](https://codesandbox.io/s/peaceful-kirch-x1t7w?file=/index.js)

```
const SelectCust = () => {
return (
  <Select
    mode="multiple"
    placeholder="Please select favourite colors"
    style={{ width: 500 }}
    name="select-multiple"
  >
    <Option value="red">Red</Option>
    <Option value="green">Green</Option>
    <Option value="blue">Blue</Option>
  </Select>
  )};

const Demo = () => {
  const onFinish = values => {
    console.log("Received values of form: ", values); // {custom:undefined}
  };

return (
  <Form name="validate_other" onFinish={onFinish}>
    <Form.Item name="custom" label="Select custom">
      <SelectCust />
    </Form.Item>

    <Form.Item>
      <Button type="primary" htmlType="submit">
        Submit
      </Button>
  </Form.Item>
</Form>
)};
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you wrap `<Select>` with `<Form.Item>` it works correctly:

```
const SelectCust = () => {
  return (
    <Form.Item name="custom" label="Select custom">
      <Select
        mode="multiple"
        placeholder="Please select favourite colors"
        style={{ width: 500 }}
        name="select-multiple"
      >
        <Option value="red">Red</Option>
        <Option value="green">Green</Option>
        <Option value="blue">Blue</Option>
      </Select>
    </Form.Item>
  );
};
```

Here is updated `Demo` component:

```
const Demo = () => {
  const onFinish = values => {
    console.log("Received values of form: ", values);
  };

  return (
    <Form name="validate_other" onFinish={onFinish}>
      <SelectCust />

      <Form.Item
        wrapperCol={{
          span: 12,
          offset: 6
        }}
      >
        <Button type="primary" htmlType="submit">
          Submit
        </Button>
      </Form.Item>
    </Form>
  );
};
```

---

**EDIT 1**

It seemed wrong to me that wrapping `<Select>` with `<Form.Item>` solved the problem, so I looked up [`<Form>` documentation](https://ant.design/components/form/).

Here is updated code:

```
const SelectCust = props => {
  return (
    <Select
      mode="multiple"
      placeholder="Please select favourite colors"
      onChange={props.onColorChange}
    >
      <Option value="red">Red</Option>
      <Option value="green">Green</Option>
      <Option value="blue">Blue</Option>
    </Select>
  );
};

const Demo = () => {
  const [form] = Form.useForm();

  const onFinish = values => console.log(values);

  const handleColorChanged = value => {
    form.setFieldsValue({ custom: value });
  };

  return (
    <Form name="validate_other" form={form} onFinish={onFinish}>
      <Form.Item name="custom" label="Select custom">
        <SelectCust onColorChange={handleColorChanged} />
      </Form.Item>

      <Form.Item
        wrapperCol={{
          span: 12,
          offset: 6
        }}
      >
        <Button type="primary" htmlType="submit">
          Submit
        </Button>
      </Form.Item>
    </Form>
  );
};
```

Update has 3 important steps:

1. Add `const [form] = Form.useForm()` in the beginning of `Demo` component
2. Implement `handleColorChanged` function and pass it as props to `SelectCust`. Handler sets form value by calling `form.setFieldsValue()`.
3. Pass `from` as props to `<Form>` component